# ASP.NET Web API 2 external logins with VK Vkontakte in AngularJS app

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, vk

I recently read Taiseer’s post on “ASP.NET Web API 2 external logins with Facebook and Google in AngularJS app”.  I got my solution working perfectly with Google and Facebook.  I decided to extend the project to support Vk.
Does anyone know how I can obtain the user id and app id like the Google implementation.  In the code below I’m trying to call a similar call like the one for Google and retrieve the user id and app id.?

```
else if (provider == "Google")
{
    verifyTokenEndPoint = string.Format(@"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?
    access_token={0}", accessToken);
}
else if (provider == "Vkontakte")
{
    verifyTokenEndPoint = string.Format(@"https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?
    client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:26264/signin-vkontakte");

}
```

Comment: information is not enough suggest you to add more details